# Can I replicate my ADF dataflow by using SQL stored procedure to transform JSON

Tags: sql, json, azure-data-factory

I understand this may not be too precise, so feel free to delete.

I am currently using Azure Data Factory as an ETL pipeline to transform JSON files that come in daily, with the same [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNp2Y.png), and load them into Azure SQL- [ADF Dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9DPM.png) [ADF Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACqHv.png) [Output to SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7cVP.png)

This process is working exactly as I want, but we would like to move everything on premise.

I have a powershell script that will move files from sftp to local, I'd like to then use a stored procedure to transform them into their respective tables.

However, I have very limited experience with SQL and creating such a procedure to parse these rather large files seems intimidating

My current ADF process is entirely automated- copied from sftp server to blob storage, ran through parametrized dataflow pipeline for transformations on trigger, and loaded into SQL

I would like to maintain this same functionality, ie. no manual input to run process

I'm aware of OPENJSON + cross apply and made an [attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP5QQ.png), if anyone can point me in the right direction (if what im asking is possible using t-SQL)- my code is moot just using as an example.

tldr; Can I replicate my ADF pipeline + dataflow by using a SQL stored procedure to parse complex json file?

Comment: Why is the cost "way out of hand"? How many cores are you using on your IR? Are you using a 10-min TTL?

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT Incurring ~ 4vcore hours per run. 2 runs a day and I'm only moving 10 files total . I am using general purpose 8 cores with a 10 minute ttl.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT  will be scaling up to 50 files a day soon and at that cost it isn't feasible

Comment: How long is each data flow taking? If you are only running 2x/day, then you don't need TTL. So if each data flow takes 5 mins, that should be ~$4/day

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT Each flow is taking taking around 3 minutes so pipeline is running for about 15 total 2x a day. How do I go about disabling ttl?

Comment: Either use the Auto Resolve Azure IR or create a new IR with 0 TTL

Comment: total 30 mins a day of data flows (4x4 GP) should cost a few dollars